# How to move the Windows Startup folder

Tags: windows, windows-registry

I made a backup of my startup folder, and somehow Windows thought the backup that was on my desktop was my actual startup folder, so when I deleted it the task manager started [showing nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOYda.png).

When I do <kbd>WIN+R</kbd> and enter `shell:startup` it says it couldn't be found.

Both `%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` contain multiple items. Why do these not show up in the task manager?

Comment: There are two (at least, depending on the number of users on your PC) Startup folders. One is user-specific, and can be accessed directly with the "shell:startup" command in the Run box, the other is OS-wide (so to speak), and can be accessed WITH ELEVATED RIGHTS via "shell:common startup", also from the Run box, by pressing the Shift key while you click on OK. Apparently, it's your own Startup folder that got canned. Windows's seems OK. Good news is, you can rebuild it by navigating to C:\Users\YourUsername\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\ and create a new Startup folder

Comment: You'll have to restart your PC when you're done, BTW.

Comment: One thing I failed to mention, and I apologize: the name "Startup" may be different in your native language, or at least in the display language Windows uses. In French, for example, it's called "Démarrage". If you use the "shell:startup" command, it'll take you to the right place, but you must name the newly-created folder according to the display language Windows uses.

Answer (score 0):

`Task Manager\Startup` only shows items from two places:

- C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

This is the user Startup folder and can be conveniently opened in Explorer with <kbd>WIN+R</kbd> and "shell:startup".

- %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

This is the system Startup folder (ie. "All users") and can be opened in Explorer with <kbd>WIN+R</kbd> and "shell:common startup". Note the comment from @Didier: Simply re-create these folders if they get accidentally deleted.

The registry entries you refer to are not displayed in Task Manager. These usually get added by software that came pre-loaded with your computer or software that has since been installed. These registry entries are unknown by many users and a major source of "slow PC syndrome".

I would recommend backing up the following registry keys with right-click `Export`:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run (x64 Windows only)
```

Once safely backed up, carefully review each item in these locations and delete if not required. You can always restore from the backup if you accidentally delete something you need.

Comment: I attempted what you suggested and it did not work. I found programs in the registry and moved them to the user startup folder, and they didn't start at all. When I run `shell:startup` it says it could not be found.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Your question appears to ask about items in `Task Manager\Startup`, not about moving registry items to the `shell:startup` folder. This is trickier. I can adapt the answer to describe how to do this if you want, but in principle: Move `HKCU\...\Run` items to `shell:startup` and `HKLM\...\Run` items to `shell:common startup`. Moving doesn't mean copy and paste! You'll have to set up a shortcut or batch file to run the program in the registry. But why move them at all? Now you know about the `Run` registry keys, just look there. Please clarify in your question.

Comment: Task manager doesn't show the items in shell:startup. In fact, when I run shell:startup it doesn't redirect me to a folder at all, it just shows an error message.

Comment: How about you restart in Safe Mode and try from there? Most programs that the user defines as starting when your user session opens can be inscribed in Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run in Regedit, as AlainD mentioned. From there, you right-click in the right pane -> New > STRING (even on a 64-bit PC), name the new entry as the program you want to start on boot, press Enter twice, and paste the path of the executable, then press Enter again and restart. Restarting without Fast Startup is preferable, but not mandatory. Works with DWORD too.